# How to validate while typing in textbox using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my page I am Having 5 `TextBoxes` and 1 `DropDownlist` box

1. Name (It should allow only alphabets)
2. UserName (It should allow both alphabets and numeric)
3. EmailID (Email format)
4. PhoneNo (Only Integers
5. Gender
6. Password (Combination of alphates and numeric)

**The above things should validate in while typing itself and If the format is correct tick image should display.....**

If we press tab without entering data error message should display below the `TextBox`
Please kindly help me...

I am fresher and new to mvc3..

```
Below is the code i have created. Now I need to validate.... please tell me how to do it
    <table>   

    <tr>
    <td> @Html.Label("FirstdName")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("FirstName")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
    <td> @Html.Label("Username")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("Username")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Username)</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
    <td> @Html.Label("Password")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("Password")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td> @Html.Label("ConfirmPassword")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("ConfirmPassword")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
    <td> @Html.Label("Phone")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("Phone")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Phone)</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
       <td> @Html.Label("Gender")</td>
    <td>  @Html.DropDownListFor(Per => Per.Gender, new[]{
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Male",Value="Male"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Female",Value="Female"},
}, "--Select--")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Gender)</td>

    </tr>


      <tr>
    <td> @Html.Label("Email")</td>
           <td>  @Html.TextBox("Email")</td>
      <td>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)</td>
    </tr>
    </table>



    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Hey Raj,Welcome to SO. Being a fresher,you came up with a nice app idea. +1 for your idea. But you will have to take a step and work to implement it. Share with us some code what you have written. Everyone is here to help. And ready made codes can't be provided here.

Comment: validation on typing should be dome on the client side, which basically means for you: jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Validation in MVC 3 is based on Annotations or Attributes which the model we are binding with the view . Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249452/ASP-NET-MVC3-Validation-Basic) out and u will know.
As you put the Validation Attributes , they are handled on the client side with the help of unobstrusive javascript. And it handles the way it should be handled automatically. Adding custom logic could be done with the help of jquery (like showing tick marks and messages alternately).
Raj , in here you wont get ready code snippets made for you when you havent tried yet.
So this is a General piece of advice . Come up with the issues you are facing and you will get the help from the awesome fraternity of yours. And off track Welcome to Tech world dude !